# Provider com.ontotext.trree.plugin.externalsync.impl.lucene4.Lucene4Plugin could not be instantiated

Tags: graphdb

I am using GraphDB Free v8.8.1 runtime and during repository initialization I am receiving the following error:

```
25055 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.config.AbstractParameter  - Configured parameter 'register-plugins' to default value '[]'
25055 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.trree.free.GraphDBFreeSchemaRepository  - Registering external plugins...
25056 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.trree.free.GraphDBFreeSchemaRepository  - Scanning /home/tioannid/graphdb-free-8.8.1/lib/plugins/sparql-mm for plugins
25057 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.PluginManager  - Registering plugin sparql-mm
25058 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.trree.free.GraphDBFreeSchemaRepository  - Scanning /home/tioannid/graphdb-free-8.8.1/lib/plugins/lucene-connector for plugins
25064 [main] ERROR com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.ServiceLocator  - Provider com.ontotext.trree.plugin.externalsync.impl.lucene4.Lucene4Plugin could not be instantiated
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.ServiceLocator.locateExternal(ServiceLocator.java:93)
    at com.ontotext.trree.OwlimSchemaRepository.initPlugins(OwlimSchemaRepository.java:1998)
    at com.ontotext.trree.OwlimSchemaRepository.initializeInternal(OwlimSchemaRepository.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.sail.helpers.AbstractSail.initialize(AbstractSail.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sail.SailRepository.initializeInternal(SailRepository.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.base.AbstractRepository.initialize(AbstractRepository.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.manager.LocalRepositoryManager.createRepository(LocalRepositoryManager.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.manager.RepositoryManager.getRepository(RepositoryManager.java:424)
    at gr.uoa.di.rdf.Geographica2.graphdbsut.GraphDBSUT$GraphDB.excGeoSPARQLDDLQuery(GraphDBSUT.java:255)
    at gr.uoa.di.rdf.Geographica2.graphdbsut.RepoUtil.main(RepoUtil.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.ServiceLocator$ExternalPluginLoader.loadClass(ServiceLocator.java:163)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 14 more
25066 [main] WARN  com.ontotext.trree.free.GraphDBFreeSchemaRepository  - No plugins found at /home/tioannid/graphdb-free-8.8.1/lib/plugins/lucene-connector
25066 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.trree.free.GraphDBFreeSchemaRepository  - Scanning /home/tioannid/graphdb-free-8.8.1/lib/plugins/dependencies-plugin for plugins
25070 [main] INFO  com.ontotext.trree.sdk.impl.PluginManager  - Registering plugin dependencies-plugin
```

Is there something missing from the GraphDB distribution?

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by incompatible Lucene connector configuration. Do you have any external plugins (-Dregister-external-plugins=.... in the VM Options). Also make sure you have json-simple-1.1.1.jar in graphdb/lib directory. Did you make any changes to the distribution itself?

Comment: I am using -Xmx24g and -Dregister-external-plugins=/home/tioannid/graphdb-free-8.8.1/lib/plugins. I use the same JVM options in the Netbeans->Project Properties->Run->VM Options text box.

Comment: The only thing I did was to my module's POM file, which was to exclude from the graphdb-free-runtime dependency the following artifacts: rdf4j-storage, rdf4j-sail-lucene, rdf4j-sail-lucene-spin, rdf4j-sail-elasticsearch and rdf4j-sail-solr. This modification was a suggestion from Yasen Marinov in a similar question I had posted with title "GraphDB 8.6.1 Free - Geospatial predicates don't work with runtime but work with Workbench"

Comment: json-simple-1.1.1.jar is in /home/tioannid/graphdb-free-8.8.1/lib